# How much production does chopping woods or rainforest give in Civilization VI?

Tags: civilization-6

I don't have access to the game right now and I'm trying to calculate how many woods/rainforests it will take to chop out a Chichen Itza. Online Speed, King Difficulty, Renaissance Era. With Magnus.

I didn't see a table of "how much production chopping woods gives you, by era" on the wiki, that would be useful if anyone has it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gains from chopping woods or any other resource do not increase by era. The base amount you receive from a chop depends on the number of technological and cultural advances (technologies) you possess. The tooltip does account for your advances when you hover over the respective "harvest" button. This also accounts for game speed. You only need to factor in your modifiers from, say, Magnus being established in that city and a policy that gives you bonus production towards wonders, in your case.